# How to change number of steps of solutions with ode45 - Matlab?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, matlab

I have the next function:

```
function [f,R]=fun_z_proba(z,p,beta)  % function definition
ri=0.7;
R=ri-z*(ri-1);
f=zeros(4,size(p,2));
f(1,:)=-32.*beta./(R.^4.*p(1,:));
f(2,:)=(-8*f(1,:)./R-f(1,:).*p(2,:))./p(1,:);
f(3,:)=(-p(2,:).*f(2,:)-8.*f(2,:)./R-8.*f(1,:)./(R.*R.*p(1,:))-f(1,:).*p(3,:))./p(1,:);
f(4,:)=(-f(2,:).*p(3,:)-f(3,:).*p(2,:)+8.*(-f(3,:)./R-   (f(2,:)./p(1,:)-p(2,:).*f(1,:)./(p(1,:).*p(1,:)))./(R.*R))    -f(1,:).*p(4,:))./p(1,:);
end
```

and I am calling it with

```
beta=1:0.1:5;
f=cell(1,numel(beta)); 
ctr=1; 
for beta = beta
[f{ctr},p{ctr}]=ode45(@(z,p)fun_z_proba(z,p,beta), [1 0], [1; 0; 0; 0]);
ctr=ctr+1;
end
```

Results important for me are stored in `p`, but for every value of `beta` I got different number of values for `p`. Is there some way to get the  same number of `p` values in every case for beta, under the same conditions like here?

Comment: This seems to be a question about some programming language, not a question about mathematics, right? So, maybe it should be posted to a coding site, instead?

Comment: Which one coding site?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com is the coding site. "Code review" exists for improvements on working code, "scientific computing" for algorithmic questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want values at fixed locations, call the method with these locations in the place of `tspan`.

You could also use the dense output option to have an interpolation function over the whole interval. See [Matlab documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html#bu3ujz9) how to invoke it and use its result.